# В vk api спарсить 100 000 результатов поиска?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть парсер он парсит группы по запросу всего их около 100.000 результатов но после 1.000 никак не идет дальше выводит сообщение IndexError: list index out of range.

```
offset=1001
count=1
while True:
    groups=vk_api.groups.search(q='натяжные потолки', offset=offset, count=count)
    group=groups['items'][0]['screen_name']
    offset += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(group)
```

Comment: смените значение offset на 2000, и скажите что происходит при этом

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Собирайте группы по вашему запросу сразу пачками: `count=1000`, например.

Comment: @insolor так и делаю но по городам но  
IndexError: list index out of range цbкл изменен на while offset != counts где counts количество групп в городе

Comment: @ДмитрийИпатов, возможно срабатывает какое-то ограничения контакта по количеству search запросов. Проверяйте, что вам вернул api, если ошибку - делайте паузу минут на 15, пробуйте снова.

Comment: @insolor lfr вот дело то в том что api не ругается тк обычно в pycharm выдает куод ошибки а так просто ругается на то что типо значения нет

Comment: @ДмитрийИпатов, контакт вместо ошибки вам может просто возвращать пустой результат поиска. Проверяйте, что `groups['items']` у вас не пустой, иначе будет указанная ошибка при обращении к `groups['items'][0]`.

Comment: @insolor сейчас опробую это идея чет тупанул)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день. Используя данный метод VK API вы можете получить только первые 1000 записей, даже если используете параметр offset. Тут ошибка не в вашем коде. Это ограничение ВКонтакте. В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/groups.search) об этом сказано.

А в вашем коде ошибка происходит из-за того, что VK присылает пустой результат, а вы пытаетесь обратиться к нулевому элементу из списка. Отсюда и `IndexError`

Comment: да я понимаю это, но смотрите я делаю выборку по городу например спб дает 745 результатов или любой др город в условии цикла говорю while offset != 999 но спустя 1/3 общего количества выводит такую ошибку, в чем проблемма?

Comment: Перед строчкой group = ... Напишите print(groups) и покажите, что скрипт вывел последнее перед ошибкой

Comment: проблема решилась спасибо